# Why was this question migrated

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions, migration

This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166215/would-stative-verb-in-past-an-exception) was migrated to English Learners site. On [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (though [English Learners Help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) center also says it) it says:

> Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Word choice and usage

And this seems like a perfectly reasonable question and I think it belongs better on English Language  & Usage as opposed to those learning English. Why was the reasoning behind the migration?

Comment: The questioner manages [fiendishly complicated mathematics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5176/infinitely-repeated-game-prisoners-dilemma/5177#5177) with ease and gets up-voted for it several times over, but clearly struggles with the English language.

Comment: The question itself seems like a matter of linguistics, which is on-topic for EL&U. Questions about linguistics can sometimes look very basic, but they can yield substantial answers that are informative and interesting.

Comment: Should it not be '_What_ was the reasoning ...' ?

Answer (score 5):

I migrated it because it was from someone who is trying to learn English, and didn’t understand a would-be “rule” they were presented with.

Comment: You may want to explain that you're using scare quotes (I assume) because many of these "rules" are either gross oversimplifications or outright false.  ELL deals with such "rules" on a regular basis, while EL&U would probably just respond with a bewildered "that's not how it works!"

Comment: @Kevin: I think we're entitled to assume the target user base of ELU would know perfectly well that many grammatical "rules" are either gross oversimplifications or outright false. Trotting it out again and again here on ELU simply encourages people who should be using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) to suppose this is the right place to be.